# Why can't we see the camera?

Tags: film-techniques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies)

In a lot of movies, we see, a character is standing in front of a mirror and watching him/her self. From our view, it looks like we are just standing behind the person. We can also see the subjects face in the mirror. So why can't we see the camera in the mirror? How do they cover the camera?

Comment: True - however, this question deals specifically with 'face-on' shots.

Comment: @Nobby The answer to that other question covers this one.