# How was this shot in Contact (1997) really made?

Tags: film-techniques, contact

There was this tricky mirror scene in [Contact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884/)

[image]

The effect is: the camera is moving backwards, always facing a character running towards something and keeping the same distance from that character (who does turns, goes upstairs, etc) and always facing it, during the whole shot. When the character's hand reaches (near the camera) what appears to be a cabinet door, and opens it, the cabinet's mirror moves on the side and the image we had moves with it, as if everything (or at least the last part of the run toward the cabinet) was filmed in the cabinet's mirror (with the camera facing the cabinet, not the character).

How was this scene really made?

Is it really a mirror shot or something else?

Comment: Related : [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies) and [Lady in the Lake 1947 (Mirror Scene)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37231/lady-in-the-lake-1947-mirror-scene)

Comment: Could you describe the effect, for posterity purposes?

Comment: @WeckarE. : the effect is : the camera is moving backwards, always facing a character running towards something and keeping the same distance from that character (who does turns, goes upstairs, etc) and always facing it, during the whole shot. When the character's hand reaches (near the camera) what appears to be a cabinet door, and opens it, the cabinet's mirror moves on the side and the image we had moves with it, as if everything (or at least the last part of the run toward the cabinet) was filmed **in** the cabinet's mirror (with the camera facing the cabinet, not the character).

Comment: @OlivierDulac I added your description to the question.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel that comment not need to added in the question. Its more of an anwer like comment

Comment: @irsha It seems to me to be mostly a description of the scene, which was important for me to understand the question at all. I see how the description partly points to how it was made, but only as a way to describe it. I have now seen the video of it, and it's a nice description of the scene, but not of how it's made. It says "as if filmed in the mirror" at the point it get's interesting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's mostly a **CGI effect** with blue screening / masking, motion tracking etc.

There's a YouTube explanation by the movie's Cinematographer Don Burgess

Also another by *Contact*'s visual effects supervisors Ken Ralston and Stephen Rosenbaum

Comment: A really damn good shot.

Comment: Super clever shot too. I wonder if that's "been around", or if Don Burgess pretty much came up with it on his own.

Comment: Can you summarize the effect in a few words for those that don't have the bandwidth and time to go through the full videos?

Comment: @PlasmaHH take 2 videos, one of the person running up there and standing by mirror, and the other being that person opening the mirror thing. Replace the mirror's reflection with green screen on second video and place first video's last frames.

Comment: honestly if i had picked an example of this effect this wouldn't have been the scene I would have picked... the angle of the mirror and it's relatively small size doesn't give me any reason to suggest that a camera should be visible in it even without special effects.

Comment: @Michael Whether the camera should be visible in the mirror doesn't have much to do with the trickiness of the shot.