# How was the scene of the mirror in "Mr. Nobody" recorded?

Tags: film-techniques, mr-nobody

How was the scene of Jared Leto looking at his reflection and the camera moving through the mirror recorded?

This is the scene:

I still can't figure how they did it.

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies?rq=1

Comment: and...- https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80284/how-was-this-shot-in-contact-1997-really-made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, using the [same techiniques](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80284/how-was-this-shot-in-contact-1997-really-made) as described for *Contact*.

> **The Shot:** In one scene, Jared Leto's character approaches a mirror, and the camera zooms in. He then walks away from the mirror and the camera follows him through the glass on the other side.
>
> **How They Did It:** What looks like one shot is actually two. The first shot is of Leto crossing the room and approaching the "mirror." In reality, the mirror was blank, a green screen. When they shot the second time, Leto became his own reflection. He approached the camera, copying his movements from the first shot in reverse. Then he walked away, and the shot continued. By superimposing the second shot on the mirror, the camera seems to go through the looking glass.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.thegeektwins.com/2014/05/5-mind-blowing-sci-fi-movie-mirror.html)</sup>