# Mirror shot without camera reflection in "Velvet Buzzsaw"

Tags: effects, cinematography, velvet-buzzsaw

In the film *Velvet Buzzsaw*, there is a unique piece of reflective art, 'Sphere'.

There are a couple of camera shots where we see the sphere, but the camera cannot be seen in the reflection:

[image: woman's reflection on a metallic sphere]

How are these camera shots made?

Comment: Related if not a duplicate - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80284/how-was-this-shot-in-contact-1997-really-made

Comment: Related [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies)

Comment: Black Swan is famous for having a ton of mirror shots. In this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GiBoNQo9is .. at 00:30 seconds, you can see a before and after (with and without the camera man).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with simple CGI (computer-generated imagery). In the original shot, the camera is visible. Before the movie is released, digital artists simply replace the reflection of the camera with something that looks like the reflection of the room.

This is the same technique that is used to hide the wires & ropes that hold actors up when they're "flying".

Comment: The same thing was done for the doorknob and reflective lenses in *The Matrix*.