# How did Kubrick shoot HAL's "eye" in 2001: A Space Odyssey?

Tags: cinematography, 2001-a-space-odyssey

How did Kubrick shoot HAL's "eye" in *2001: A Space Odyssey*? We see the reflection of the astronauts approaching HAL, but not the camera.

[image: 2001: A Space Odyssey]

How was it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't see a reflection. What you see is an actor coming towards the camera. The HAL lense and light reflexes are added from a different layer.

In Odyssey Kubrick used a technique called ["Front Screen Projection"](http://www.iso1200.com/2014/01/diy-front-projection-technique-used-by.html)

A technology that uses projecting a pre-recorded movie on a very reflective material (Scotchlite by 3M in the case of 2001:SO) using a one way mirror set at 45 degrees toward the projector. Beetwen the mirror and Scotchlite the actor was placed (or in case of 2001:SO the whole scenography). The camera record that through that one way mirror.

Here's a picture of the setup they used (photo taken from Stanley Kubrick Exibition in National Museum in Krakow/Poland).

[image]

In the left part of the blue cube you can see HAL's eye. On the black wall a pre-recorded movie (or in the case of this exibition - visitors) were present.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays CGI would be used for a scene like this (see [Mirror shot without camera reflection in "Velvet Buzzsaw"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97029/mirror-shot-without-camera-reflection-in-velvet-buzzsaw)).

CGI Lens shot:

[image: CGI Lens shot]

But since that technique was most likely not available at the time and might also not have been a great fit for Kubricks artistic approach, there must be a practical solution at works here. 
Other movies have done similar things as discussed in [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies).

I would suggest that Kubrick used a combination of multiple techniques for the given effect.
Similar to the scene in the linked SO, it might not a reflection but instead a lensed **window** into a room with the actor/astronaut and most of the lightning. 
The yellow light in the very center, might be a smart reflection from the cameras side using a slightly different technique of using an off-center object to be reflected towards the off-center camera, having them both appear centered (this is the go-to practical mirror-filming technique).

Off-center mirror shot:

[image: Simple off-center mirror shot]

The framing of the lens might also have been on the cameras side and been carefully lit to have the desired look. Afterall, Kubrick was a master of lightning as well.